# How to insert a value in the beginning of a single column tibble

Tags: tibble

I have a single column tibble ABC.

```
ABC
a
b
c
```

I want to insert d in the first position so that it looks like

```
ABC
d
a
b
c
```

I did typeof(X) and it showed list (I don't know why because it is a tibble). So I did prepend(X,'d') but it did not work. This is just a toy example; I cannot paste the actual code. But I hope my intent is clear. Can someone help?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe you think this is the correct solution to a problem, when really it isn't.

Comment: I want to consider the regressor ABC on a lagged basis. My plan is to insert a value in the beginning, and then delete the first row of the tibble.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to do `df %>% mutate(ABC_lagged = c('d', lag(ABC))`

Comment: @Jack Brookes Thank you. This is better. I tried this out on x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Name" = c("John","Dora")) with x%>%mutate(lag_age=c(36,lag(Age))) but got the message "Error: wrong result size (3), expected 2 or 1". But lag(c(21,15)) in isolation gives NA 21 as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(ABC = c("a", "b", "c"))

tibble(ABC = c("d")) %>% 
  full_join(df)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  ABC  
  <chr>
1 d    
2 a    
3 b    
4 c
```

Comment: The use of full_join is clever. Nice hack. Thank you.

Comment: Although the solution is great it is a little unfortunate that prepend('d',ABC) does not work. It is very simple and intuitive. Why should one need to do a full join? Unless there is a philosophical angle to this way of doing it that is peculiar to R, who would think of doing this?

Comment: Because it's not a good idea. Your assumed solution was not the ideal one, I just gave you a way to perform your solution. Usually it is better to post your actual problem rather than your idea of how you think you should solve the problem

Comment: Yes, agreed. But I could not post the original problem. The next best thing is to describe it which I did later.